# How to update element in XMLDocument using VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am not very familiar with XML but I am learning and I could use some assistance. I am trying to change the value of the "CipherValue" and I'm getting the error, "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd= "http:=//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://something" xmlns:soap="something">
  <soap:Body>
    <fiAPI xmlns="http://something.com" xmlns:ITI="http://www.something.com/" xmlns:ds="http://something#" xmlns:xenc="http://something#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://something.xsd">
<fiHeader Version="2.2">
  <Service Name="TST1337" Version="10.0">
    <DateTime>03-20-2020</DateTime>
    <UUID>3095725798457984579834</UUID>
  </Service>
  <Security>
    <AuthenticationMaterial>
      <SignedToken>
        <EncryptedData>
          <CipherData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <CipherValue>somereallylongencryptednumber</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedData>
      </SignedToken>
    </AuthenticationMaterial>
    <PrincipalID>Prometheus</PrincipalID>
    <TrustRelationship xmlns="http://www.Somenet.com/">TrustedUser</TrustRelationship>
  </Security>
  <Client>
    <VendorID>FNB-AK!</VendorID>
    <AppID>FNB-AK!INST000</AppID>
    <OrgID>00</OrgID>
    <SessionID></SessionID>
  </Client>
  <DataSource>
    <URI>TEST</URI>
  </DataSource>
</fiHeader>
<Request Echo="false" TypeOfRequest="GetName">
  <NameID>5371</NameID>
  <GroupName>TEST</GroupName>
  <InstNumber>00</InstNumber>
  <Sequence>1</Sequence>
  <Type>Names</Type>
  <Type>AccountNameRelationships</Type>
</Request>
</fiAPI>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The code I have tried:

```
        Dim MyXML As New XmlDocument()
        MyXML.Load("..\..\FNBAXMLFile.xml")
        Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNode = MyXML.SelectSingleNode("/fiAPI/Security/AuthenticationMaterial/SignedToken/EncryptedData/CipherData/CipherValue")
        If MyXMLNode IsNot Nothing Then
            MyXMLNode.ChildNodes(0).InnerText = "CHANGED"
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("node is Nothing")
        End If ' Save the Xml.
        MyXML.Save("C:\Temp\XmlTest.xml")
```

I updated the code I was using. I dont need to know what the existing value is, i just need to change it. When I use this code, I get a "Node is Nothing." but the node is there. I'm confused.

I removed all of the node attributes and was able to get the value I was looking for. I know I can convert the loaded xml document to a string and use String.Replace BUT I need to save the edited XML document to another folder and it seems odd to load an XML doc, convert to string, change values, then convert back to an XML document. I am thoroughly confused now.

*bangs head on desk*

I had some help and this is what we came up with:

```
        Dim MyXML As New XmlDocument()
        MyXML.Load("..\..\FNBAXMLFile.xml")
        txtResponse.Text = MyXML.OuterXml
        Dim node As XmlNodeList = MyXML.GetElementsByTagName("CipherValue")
        If node IsNot Nothing Then
            node(0).InnerText = "ALL RIGHTY THEN"
            MyXML.Save("C:\Temp\XmlTest.xml")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("node is Nothing")
        End If
```

Comment: What language are you using to manipulate your XML?

Comment: It sorta looks like VB.NET, but I'm not certain since I don't work with it regularly (and haven't for a while)... Could you edit your question with the appropriate language tag? Without knowing that though, this question "needs details".

Comment: I'm using VB.Net

Comment: @Jason you need to add that to your question as a tag so that it reaches the correct people, not just in the title. I've done it for you this time though.

Comment: Ah. Thank you :)

Comment: The problem most likely in the declaration of node variable. Try Dim node As XmlNode = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/fiAPI/Security/AuthenticationMaterial/SignedToken/EncryptedData/CipherData") instead. Also check for node being nothing before the for loop.